# How to fix "dmesg: klogctl: Permission denied" for normal user on Android?

Tags: rooting, samsung, linux, aosp, systemless-root

I have a rooted Samsung device(system-as-root). When I open `adb shell` and run the `dmesg`  then it behaves differently for `su` and `normal user`. It throws

> dmesg: klogctl: Permission denied

error when I run it without `su` shell.

Please suggest how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dmesg` calls C library's [`klogctl`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/toybox/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r49/toys/lsb/dmesg.c#101) wrapper function for kernel's [`syslog`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/klogctl.3.html) syscall which reads kernel's ring buffer by accessing `/dev/kmsg` character device. `adb shell dmesg` returns permissions denied error because `adbd` which runs with context `u:r:shell:s0` is not allowed by SELinux to read kernel log. You need to explicitly allow it (**requires root**):

```
~# supolicy --live 'allow shell kernel system syslog_read'
```

If property [`ro.logd.kernel`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/logd/README.property#10) is set to `true` (default on `debuggable` builds), Android's logging daemon (`logd`) writes kernel messages to a separate buffer named `kernel`, which can be read using `logcat` (**doesn't require root**):

```
~$ logcat -b kernel
```